# docker registry letsencrypt: Could not determine solvers

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, docker-registry

I started a private docker registry on a DigitalOcean server whose IP address resolves to *docker.example.com* (A record). The operating system is RancherOS.

```
docker run -d -p 443:5000 --name registry --restart=always \
 -v $(pwd)/var/lib/registry:/var/lib/registry \
 -v $(pwd)/auth:/auth \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_HOST=https://docker.example.com \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_CACHEFILE=/etc/docker/registry/letsencrypt.json \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=admin@example.com \
 -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=distortum \
 -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
 registry:2
```

Acme is failing to set up SSL certificates. This is in the logs:

```
2018/03/10 22:29:15 [INFO] acme: Registering account for admin@example.com
time="2018-03-10T22:29:16Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000, tls" go.version=go1.7.6 instance.id=46277ada-99d7-458e-aa24-7ef9b9009f86 version=v2.6.2
2018/03/10 22:29:44 [INFO][docker.example.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
2018/03/10 22:29:45 [INFO][docker.example.com] acme: Could not find solver for: dns-01
2018/03/10 22:29:45 [INFO][docker.example.com] acme: Could not find solver for: http-01
2018/03/10 22:29:45 http: TLS handshake error from 120.17.222.195:41255: map[docker.example.com:[docker.example.com] acme: Could not determine solvers]
```

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: It *might* have something to do with letsencrypt disabling the `tls-sni-01` challenge and the registry image not supporting the other challenges, each requiring an additional service on another port.